# Trying to view JabbR (signalR)

Tags: signalr

I try to log into http://jabbr.net/ or http://jabbr-redis.apphb.com/ to see how signalr is working and I always get the same message when I try the JabbR Login. Can anyone help me figure out what is happening on my end and how I can try Jabbr...

[image: Login Error]

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a SignalR issue. The problem is JabbR's Janrain account is over free quota and so they've disabled the account unless someone is going to start paying for it.

I believe @dfowler is working on getting off of Janrain and just doing his own authentication for JabbR.